# Scalar curvature for a given metric does not fit the expected sign and numerical factor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

For a metric given by the infinitesimal length element
\begin{equation}
\label{Special_metric}
    {\rm d}s^2=(r/r_{0})^4~c^2{\rm d}t^2-{\rm d}r^2-r^2{\rm d}\Omega^2~,\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $r$ is radius of sectional curvature, $r_{0}$ some reference value, $c$ light velocity, and ${\rm d}\Omega$ an infinitesimal surface element on the unit sphere, the calculated scalar curvature, $S=g^{ik}R_{ik}$, results in
\begin{equation}
\label{Ricci_scalar_curvature}
    S=\frac{12}{r^2},\tag{2}
\end{equation}
This expression is the same as for the scalar curvature of a 4-sphere in Euclidean space, $S=4~(4-1)/r^2$, as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature. However, the metric (1) describes a 3-dimensional hyperbolic space that can be identified with a local subset of (3+1)-dimensional Minkowski space (wiki again). The corresponding scalar curvature in that case would be equal
\begin{equation}
\label{Ricci_scalar_curvature 2}
    S=-\frac{3~(3-1)}{r^2}=-\frac{6}{r^2}.\tag{3}
\end{equation}
Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: How does the metric (1) "describe" a $3$-dimensional submanifold? It's a metric on a $4$-dimensional space.

Comment: The phrase with "3-dimensional submanifold" I have taken from wiki: "By the hyperboloid model, an n-dimensional hyperbolic space can be identified with the subset of (n + 1)-dimensional Minkowski space  (...). The parameter r is a geometrical invariant of the hyperbolic space, and the sectional curvature is K = −1/r2. The scalar curvature is thus S = −n(n − 1)/r2. The same link as in the question.

Comment: I have thought that in hyberbolic case n is equal 3 because the space has the dimension n+1 = 4.

Comment: Notice the words "hyperboloid model." We have to take one sheet of the  hyperboloid $-t^2+x^2+y^2+z^2=-1$ to get the model of hyperbolic $3$-space in *flat* Lorentz space with metric $-dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$.

Comment: I understand now, thanks. However, my main question remains. What tells me the equation (2) in connection with metric (1). Can you help there?

Comment: That's presumably just a standard computation. My standard way of doing these computations is with differential forms and the so-called method of moving frames, but you can certainly compute with Christoffel symbols or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thus, assuming my calculated S is correct, can I conclude that my metric describes  a  4-sphere in Euclidean space?

Comment: No, $r$ is a coordinate on your spacetime, not a constant. Thus, the scalar curvature is a function as you move around. If you had $r_0$ appearing, then you might say that a *constant* scalar curvature equals that of a sphere of the appropriate radius.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to understand better my problem.